# Conversion of Excel formula back to written Formula...if possible!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, education

I turn to you as a last resort, in the hope that you will forgive my Maths ignorance and help me with what may be a simple problem.

Essentially, this involves converting an excel formula to written math, if possible. As I am absolutely not a specialist in Math, I barely even know where to begin...but I am seeking a formula to express the following idea.

Essentially I am using Excel to find value a which is determined by two different equations depending on the value of $b$.

If $b > 0$, then the value of a will be determined by equation $Y$.
If $b < 0$, then the value of a will be determined by equation $Z$.

The actual excel formula is as follows: `=IF(C14>0,J14,K14)`.
It's the standard `IF` function.

So this already would be a great help...

What I am then going to do is to find the average of values of $a$ over any number of instances...so I need to sum then divide by the number of instances.

Can this be expressed in any form of mathematical formulae?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "What I am then going to do is to find the average of values of aa over any number of instances...so I need to sum then divide by the number of instances."

Comment: Sure....so say a is the value of an event, and there are 100 different events...I will just try to find the average of them. So the sum of the total divided by the number of events. Does that help or am I being too much of a layman...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. As I understand, you have a column of values; each cell in this column is returning values from your `IF` function, to give you a value for $a$. Somewhere else in your spreadsheet, you have one cell containing the fixed parameter $b$. Your `IF` function calls this value of $b$, and according to whether $b$ is positive or negative, it gives you your value of $a$. Then, what you want to do is simply average this overall column. Is this correct?

Comment: You are right on everything except for the value of parameter b. It's not a fixed value and can change for each event.

Answer (score 1):

We use a brace to show cases, so you would say $$f(b)=\begin {cases} J14 & b \gt 0\\K14 & b \le 0 \end {cases}$$ where you substitute in the formulas that generate J14 and K14.  Then if you have a bunch of points $x_i$ you could write $$sum=\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\\avg=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)$$

Comment: That's wonderful, Ross. Thank you. Is there a way of combining these into a single equation?

Comment: There are ways to hide the case statement, but they are really just hiding it.  You can use the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) to write $f(b)=H(b)J14+(1-H(b))K14$ but that is what  mean by hiding.

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect. I think I'll leave the Heaviside Step Function...as it's a little beyond my understanding. Many many thanks...

Comment: It is just a function that is $1$ when the argument is positive and zero when the argument is negative.

Comment: Thank you for that...I read the wikipedia article and understood it within my limits! But you have confirmed my understanding.